# Preparing a variable value for display using %d in Python

Tags: python, decimal

**GOAL:**

I'm trying to display (assumed float) value as a decimal, within a print call using the '%d' operator.

**PROBLEM**

Documentation states that '%d' can only take the value of a decimal. Taking this into account, I imported the 'decimal' module and attempted to convert using the decimal function. The result was not altered, and my code would return what looks like a 'floored' price for my oranges (my oranges are not happy with that). What am I doing wrong?

**CODE**

```
 import decimal

    prices = {
        "banana":4,
        "apple":2,
        "orange":1.5,
        "pear":3
        }

    stock = {
        "banana":6,
        "apple":0,
        "orange":32,
        "pear":15
        }

    for x in prices:
        print x
        print "price: %d" % (decimal.Decimal(prices[x]))

        for y in stock:
            if y == x:
                print "stock: %d" % (stock[y])
```

**RESULT**

```
orange
price: 1 // Need this to return the price (1.5)
stock: 32
pear
price: 3
stock: 15
banana
price: 4
stock: 6
apple
price: 2
stock: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print floating point numbers, use the `%f` specifier. For example, this will print the price with 2 decimal digits of precision:

```
print "price: %.2f" % prices[x]
```

See here for more documentation:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Krzysztof Kosiński; should have made a point to check how many specifier types Python provides before trying to hack things. But regarding my code; I converted my value to a decimal, why did it not display a decimal version of my value?

Comment: If you look at the documentation link that Krzysztof Kosiński posted you can see that the 'd' format is a signed **integer** decimal format.

Comment: Based on the doc, if anything with a decimal point is considered a float, then how would you represent a 'decimal' (signed integer decimal)?' I ask because the 'd' specifier expects that, but apparently my price for oranges was a float.

Comment: @brooklynsweb: ah, I think I see what's confusing you.  The word "decimal" here doesn't mean "decimal" as opposed to "integer", it means "decimal" as opposed to "hexadecimal", i.e. base 10.  `%d` specified a signed integer in base 10.

Comment: The docs here use the word 'decimal' in its definition of "a number in a base 10 representation", not as "a number that's got a decimal point in its representation" or "an instance of the Python `decimal.Decimal` class". Compare to e.g. the `%x` format specifier that displays as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my attempt.

The `%d` specifier converts the number to an **integer** of base 10. So when you do something like:

```
print "price: %d"%Decimal("1.5")
```

It would print `price:1`.

To achieve what you want, you can use the `%f` specifier:

```
print "price: %.2f"%Decimal("1.5")
```

See more on formatting [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Hope this helps!